# observable package in dart not listening for changes on map?

Tags: dart, flutter

I am actually trying to listen for changes on a map inside my Flutter app which is declared as `ObservableMap` using `Observable` package.

I am using a `StreamSubscription` to notify of any changes. But the problem is it is not listening for changes inside a map which are inside the map objects. I have included an example for reference. Please can someone tell me if I am doing anything wrong or do we have to do this in a different way.

main.dart

```
    import 'dart:async';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:observable_map_demo/globals.dart';
import 'package:observable_map_demo/second_screen.dart';

void main() => runApp(new MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: new ThemeData(

        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: new MyHomePage(title: 'Observable Demo'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);  

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => new _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {

  Map data = new Map();
  StreamSubscription changeListener;
  var change;

  @override
  void initState(){
    super.initState();
//    changeListener = observeMap.changes.listen((c){
//      setState((){
//        data = observeMap;
//        print('here');
//        print(c);
//
//      });
//    });

    change = observeMap.changes.forEach((c){
      setState((){
        print(c);
        data = observeMap;
        print('here in ');

      });

    }).whenComplete((){
      setState((){
        data = observeMap;
        print('here');

      });
    });


  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return new Scaffold(
      appBar: new AppBar(

        title: new Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: new Center(

        child: new Column(

          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
//            
          new Text(data.toString()),

            new MaterialButton(child: new Text('click for next screen'),onPressed: ()=>Navigator.push(context, new MaterialPageRoute(builder: (_)=> new SecondState())),)
          ],
        ),
      ),
       // This trailing comma makes auto-formatting nicer for build methods.
    );
  }
}
```

globals.dart:

```
import 'package:observable/observable.dart';
ObservableMap observeMap = new ObservableMap();
```

second_screen.dart:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:observable_map_demo/globals.dart';

class SecondState extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _SecondStateState createState() => new _SecondStateState();
}

class _SecondStateState extends State<SecondState> {
  int i=0;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
      body: new Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        children:<Widget>[

          new MaterialButton(onPressed: ((){
            i++;

            setState((){
              Map x = {'prayuta':'hyd'};
              Map data1 = {'hey':x};

              Map data = {'hi': data1,
              'how':'hello world'};

              observeMap.addAll(data);
              print(observeMap);
            });

          }),
            child: new Text('Hi'+observeMap.toString()),
          ),

          new MaterialButton(onPressed: ((){
            setState((){
              observeMap['hi'].remove('hey');
              print(observeMap);
            });
          }),
            child: new Text('remove'+observeMap.toString()),
          ),

        ]


      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: What do you call a variable of type Map `list`? :D

Comment: I had a brief look and would your code expect to work. I'd suggest you try to simplify the code to ensure nothing else interferes.

Comment: Thanks @GünterZöchbauer sorry for declaring map as a list. as i was trying to use lists and maps and just changed the list to maps.   i've now edited this. but the code doesnt seem to work for map changes.

Comment: Did it work when it was a list?

Comment: it actually is working absolutely fine for list. Thank you.

Comment: Are you talking about `addAll(...)` or `observeMap['hi'].remove('hey');`?

Comment: sorry for the late reply Gunter Zochbauer, even the map was working fine for    'addAll(...)'    but is not working for   'observeMap['hi'].remove('hey');'   although it works for   ' observeMap.remove('hi') '.  thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's working as intended, the observable map only recognizes if values or keys are added or removed, not when properties of values it holds are modified.

Comment: oh dear, thank you very much for your help Gunter Zochbauer, I will use an EventBus instead.

Comment: oh i've never tried redux, I will give it a go. thank you.